# How can I control the data I get from a JSON depending on its format in Java?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON file into Java objects. I'm using OkHttpClient to get this JSON. The issue is, that the JSON returned can have two different formats. If the Query parameters on the URL are correct, the JSON format will be like:

```
{
    "debugOutput": {
        "pathCalculationTime": 0,
        "pathTimes": [],
        "precalculationTime": 0,
        "renderingTime": 0,
        "timedOut": true,
        "totalTime": 0
    },
    "error": {
        "id": 0,
        "message": "PLAN_OK",
        "missing": [],
        "msg": "string",
        "noPath": true
    },
    "plan": {
        "date": 0,
        "from": {},
        "itineraries": [],
        "to": {}
    },
    "requestParameters": {
        "app_id": "string",
        "app_key": "string",
        "arriveBy": "string",
        "date": "string",
        "fromPlace": "string",
        "maxWalkDistance": "string",
        "mode": "string",
        "time": "string",
        "toPlace": "string"
    }
}
```

But if anything in the request is not correct, I'll get a JSON file like this one:

```
{
     "status": "error",
     "error":"Unexpected error"
}
```

As the only data I wanna store if the query parameters are correct is the one on the object `plan`, so far I've done this:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(jsonData).getAsJsonObject();    //jsonData is the Json file as a String.
JsonObject planJson = jsonObject.get("plan").getAsJsonObject();
plan = gson.fromJson(planJson.toString(), Plan.class);
```

But this obviously throws an Exception if the JSON data is like the second format.

How can I know which format will I get?

Comment: usually when there is an error, the API will return a http status code that is not 200 - 400, 500 or something like that

Comment: I agree with @stringy05 but if not you can also do `if (planJson.has("status")) {...`. Or you could wrap your `fromJson` call with a `try/catch` and convert to the error format if it throws.